# Binding a ComboBox in a ListView on a Property of the Tab

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I again have a problem with bindings in XAML, I cannot solve by myself. I have a `ListView` and a `ComboBox` in it. The `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` lies on the view model of a `TabControl` and so does the `ComboBox.ItemsSource`. How can I bind the `ComboBox` on this collection?

Here is my Code so far:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding ListViewSelection}"
          ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ListViewTemplate}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="...">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxSource}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding ...}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn> // ...
```

And here are just the heads of the `ItemsSource` properties in the `TabViewModel`:

```
public ObservableCollection<TypeViewModel> ComboBoxSource { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<CostViewModel> ListViewSource { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to bind the `CombBox.ItemsSource` on this property?

Comment: In the CellTemplate, at a guess: `ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ComboBoxSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"`.

Comment: Relative source can do what you want, per the previous comment. Unfortunately, your question does not make clear why every item in your `ListView` will have the same drop-down, but if for some reason the relative-source approach doesn't suit your needs, it would not be unreasonable for each `TypeViewModel` to expose its own `ComboBoxSource` property which simply delegates to the parent view model (e.g. `...ComboBoxSource { get { return _parentViewModel.ComboBoxSource; } }`. Or depending on the origin of these values, maybe even a singleton. There are lots of possible answers.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Unfortunately this didn't work for me, but I solved it now the way how KMCho explained it in the answer Section { Binding ElementName=ControlName, Path=DataContext.ComboBoxSource }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just one example.
you have a `TabViewModel` something like this.

```
public class TabViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CostViewModel> ListViewSource { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TypeViewModel> ComboBoxSource { get; set; }

    public TabViewModel()
    {
        ListViewSource = new ObservableCollection<CostViewModel>();
        ListViewSource.Add(new CostViewModel() { CostA = "A", CostB = "B" });
        ListViewSource.Add(new CostViewModel() { CostA = "1", CostB = "2" });            

        ComboBoxSource = new ObservableCollection<TypeViewModel>();
        ComboBoxSource.Add(new TypeViewModel() { TypeA = "A1", TypeB = "B1" });
        ComboBoxSource.Add(new TypeViewModel() { TypeA = "A2", TypeB = "B2" });
    }
}
```

and put the `DataContext` to your `window`

```
TabViewModel vm { get; set; }        
public Window1()
{
    vm = new TabViewModel();
    this.DataContext = vm;            
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and give a name to the `window`, binding with `ElementName`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Name="mainWnd">    
    <Grid>        
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewSource}" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="...">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWnd, Path=DataContext.ComboBoxSource}" DisplayMemberPath="TypeA"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the great example! This solved my problem.